# Is it possible to create a linux users group programmatically?

Tags: c++, linux

I'd like to know if it is possibile to create a linux users group (and also add one or more users to it) via c++ code
For the code I'm working on I need to create a group with specific privileges and to add the users that want to run my software to it.
I already created the group manually and everithing works as expected.
Now, the simplest solution to my problem would be to add to the software documentation the steps needed to create the group and to add users to it. But I'd like my software to do it automatically, if possible.
I hope that my question is clear enough. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe you just want to execute a shell script from your application that does this.